# Is it possible to return a full page after an Ajax call for one row in a table in MVC ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Quite difficult to explain, but here goes.

**Summary of question**

Is it possible to return a full page/view when the "Action" was initially called by a subset of the page ie row via Ajax.

**Background**

I am using MVC 5 ASP.NET 4.5, C# and Razor.

I have a table with an edit link for each table row. When clicked that row is turned into a editable row using

```
    <td>
    <div id="EditCommand" style="visibility:visible">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "TR", new {id = item.Id}, null)" class="edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I use this Javascript to ensure that the partial View sits within the TR tags.

```
<script>
 $('table').on('click', '.edit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        context: $(this).closest('tr'),
        success: function (result) {
            $(this).html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The "Edit" Link calls:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{return PartialView("_EditRow", myRecord);}
```

The form post then calls after saving:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Product myProduct)
{return PartialView("_DisplayRow",myRecord);}
```

Thus returning a readonly row after saving. This all works well when just editing one row which it was originally designed to do.

**Now to my question.**

Is it possible to redirect to another "Action" after saving and return to a full page view thereby breaking out of this Ajax row? At present when I try this all "Partial Views" or "Full Views" return to the row from whence it was called. To me this is similar to how an Iframe would behave.

Thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: `window.location.href="yourNewUrl";` inside the `success` handler. But that defeats the purpose of ajax!!!

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to solve this problem from the server code as part of an Action, or does it have to be via Javascript on the client?

Comment: .... well you just wouldn't use an ajax link, you would use a normal link.... then in the Action you can return RedirectToAction instead of a view... I think you are misunderstanding

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem I have is that I am using Ajax to effectively change a table row from display to an edit row and I do this by returning a partial view. However as I am now doing this, it seems that I am now constrained to returning views into this "row view" only. Whatever I do be it a RedirectToAction which has its own View or via a direct View, I still get the View returned to the row, and not full page. Hence my issue. I appreciate your help

Comment: @SamJolly, What is the reason you want to update the whole table? Are you wanting to edit multiple rows in one action and post all changes (it which case you using the wrong approach)

Comment: There are many third party controls out there that can help you do this without having to re-invent the wheel, but if you are wanting to do this for the challenge of it. you may have to abandon having a (partial) view for each Table row and instead manipulate using front end coding

Comment: I have sorted it. My answer was inspired by @Shyju. Basically I have created a seperate partial view with just some JS with "window.location.href="yourNewUrl";" where the "href" gets populated by Razor and it works a treat. So a big thank you all. If you want to put it as an answer then I can mark it.